# Read Tab-Separated-Columns into Lists - Java

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

Tab-Separated File:

```
2019-06-06 10:00:00 1.0
2019-06-06 11:00:00     2.0
```

I'd like to iterate over the file once and add the value of each column to a list.

My working approach would be:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
ArrayList<Double> List_1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> List_2 = new ArrayList<Double>();

String[] values = null;
String fileName = "File.txt";
File file = new File(fileName);
try
    {
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        try {
        String data = inputStream.nextLine();
        values = data.split("\\t");
        if (values[1] != null && !values[1].isEmpty() == true) {
            double val_1 = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
            List_1.add(val_1);
            }
        if (values[2] != null && !values[2].isEmpty() == true) {
            double val_2 = Double.parseDouble(values[2]);
            List_2.add(val_2);
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception){   
        }
        }
        inputStream.close();
        }
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(List_1);
System.out.println(List_2);
}
}
```

I get:

```
[1.0]
[2.0]
```

It doesn't work without the checks for `null`, `ìsEmpty` and the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I would appreciate any hints on how to save a few lines while keeping the scanner approach.

Comment: "Tab separated comma separated values"  So not a CSV then?

Comment: yes I changed that

Comment: I recommend not saving it as a `.csv` in your code either too, its deceptive.  Maybe use [.tsv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) or `.txt`

Comment: You should probably check the size of values before using values[1] and values[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean up your code some by using [try-with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to open and close the `Scanner` for you:

```
try (Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file))
{
//your code...
}
```

This is useful because the `inputStream` will be closed automatically once the `try` block is left and you will not need to close it manually with `inputStream.close();`.

Additionally if you really want to "save lines" you can also combine these steps:

```
double val_2 = Double.parseDouble(values[2]);
List_2.add(val_2);
```

Into a single step each, since you do not actually use the `val_2` anywhere else:

```
List_2.add(Double.parseDouble(values[2]));
```

Finally you are also using `!values[1].isEmpty() == true` which is comparing a `boolean` value to `true`.  This is typically bad practice and you can reduce it to `!values[1].isEmpty()` instead which will have the same functionality.  Try not to use `==` with `boolean`s as there is no need.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a Map of Lists using column number as a key. This approach gives you "unlimited" number of columns and exactly the same output than one in the question.

```java
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Map<Integer, List<Double>> listMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Double>>();
        String[] values = null;
        String fileName = "File.csv";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
            String data = inputStream.nextLine();
            values = data.split("\\t");
            for (int column = 1; column < values.length; column++) {
                List<Double> list = listMap.get(column);
                if (list == null) {
                    listMap.put(column, list = new ArrayList<Double>());
                }
                if (!values[column].isEmpty()) {
                    list.add(Double.parseDouble(values[column]));
                }
            }
        }
        inputStream.close();
        for(List<Double> list : listMap.values()) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like below:

```
BufferedReader bfr = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("inputFileDir.tsv"));
String line = null;
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>(100);
while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] cols = line.split("\\t");
    List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<>(cols);
    //at this line your expected list of cols of each line is ready to use. 
    listOfLists.add(outputList);
}
```

As a matter of fact, it is a simple code in java. But because it seems that you are a beginner in java and code like a python programmer, I decided to write a sample code to let you have a good start point. good luck

Comment: He does say he wants to keep `Scanner` however.

Comment: Is that really what is declared in the question title? stick to the main point plz not the definite marginal points

Comment: It does not need to say it in the title, but he wrote it out at the bottom: `I would appreciate any hints on how to save a few lines while keeping the scanner approach.` and he tagged it with `Scanner`.